# try/catch with @Transactional throws TransactionException instead of catch's exception

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, transactions

I have a problem, my controller is marked as `@Transactional` and I have a method, that has `try/catch` block that is supposed to catch `DataIntegrityViolationException`, and everything is fine, the `catch` is executed, but in the end I do not see the message from `catch`, but I can see this:

```
Caused by Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
Caused by TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
```

Adding `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)` doesn't solve the problem, I still get the `TransactionException` instead of `DataIntegrityViolationException` exception,

The method is like this:

```
def delete() {
 try {
   something.delete();
 } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
   flash.message = "some error"
 }
```

Comment: "the catch is executed, but in the end I do not see the message from catch" - Can you show the code that you expect to display the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't make a transactional controller.

Second, `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown from `something.delete();`, but `TransactionException` is thrown when you return from the method marked with `@Transactional` - Spring's transaction manager tries to commit the transaction, which has already been marked for rollback because of `DataIntegrityViolationException`. What you should do is to move `@Transactional` into the service layer and wrap the call to it with `try-catch` within controller's method.

Comment: I know, that the controller shouldn't be transactional, it's a commercial project and I was told not to change it yet, because we do not want to make such a refactor yet.... so... would you say there is not any other solution for that instead of moving `@Transational` to a service? What would it change if anyway the transaction would be rolledback?

Comment: Well, what I understood from your question is that your problem is about error message you are expecting from catch block. Of course, transaction will be rolled back, there's no way to prevent it as soon as insert/update into the DB failed with `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

So if you want to rid this error, then you need to do validation of incoming data before interacting with the DB and throw `DataIntegrityViolationException` manually in case one of inserted/updated params is out of allowed bounds.

Comment: thank you very much, after long weeks of research this comment explained me more, than anything else :) everything is working after creating a separate service :)